# window.open to a download followed by a window.location change doesn't download

Tags: javascript, http, browser, window.open, window.location

In my application's javascript we run `window.open(location1)` followed by `window.location = location2` and it seems that 9 times out of 10 `window.open` never occurs. This is in contrast to what is supposed to happen, location changes shouldn't stop execution. This occurs in Chrome and Safari.

The export button links to a page with the content below. It first opens its own url, this time with `action=go` to trigger the actual download headers being set for the file, etc. Then it changes the location back to the original page.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        window.open(window.location + '&action=go', '_blank');
        window.location = '{{ original_url }}';    
    };
</script>
```

This worked up until a few months ago. Now it only works one out of five or ten times. I've tried delaying the location change, etc. but it has no effect.

Comment: This feels weird - instead, build an `<a>`, set all its values including some `setAttribute("target", "_blank")`, add that to the body once the page is ready, and then `a.click()` it, followed by `a.parentNode.removeChild(a)` if you _absolutely_ need to open a second URL every time people open your original page URL.

Comment: Does the failure continue if you turn off pop-up blocking in Chrome or Safari? If it looks like a pop-up ...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans your solution is what worked. Could you please submit it as an answer and I'll mark it correct?

Comment: A (slightly more elaborate) answer written.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feels weird. What you probably want to do instead is build an `<a>`, set all its values including an "open in new tab" instruction, add that to the body once the page is ready, and then click-and-remove it:

```
const loadSecondary = () => {
  let secondary = document.createElement(`a`);
  secondary.style.display = `none`;
  secondary.setAttribute(`target`, `_blank`);
  secondary.href = ...

  document.body.appendChild(secondary);
  secondary.click();
  document.body.removeChild(secondary);
};

document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, loadSecondary);
```

The upside of this is that (a) it's a normal link so you don't have to deal with window.open parameters and popup blocking, and (b) it's a normal link (again =) so it's added to the browsing history by the browser automatically as well.